# My Javascript Form Validator isn't working (?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I can't figure out why my script isn't working. I'd like to validate the username and the password when clicking the submit button, but when I type a value that should return an error message the submit just executes normally.

Comment: Does your JavaScript file as reference from your source actually exist?

Comment: You're pushing error messages to `errormsg` but never doing anything with it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug when you are referencing the form element.

You have taken the reference as

```
var form = document.getElementById("form").value;
```

But it should be

```
var form = document.getElementById("form");
```

```js
    
var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
var pasw = document.getElementById("pasw").value;
var cpasw = document.getElementById("cpasw").value;
var form = document.getElementById("form");

var name_v = /^[a-zA-Z0-9-]+$/;
var pasw_v = /^(?=.*\d).{8,}$/;

form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  debugger;
  let errormsg = [];

  if (!name_v.test(name)){
    errormsg.push("The Name must not contain spaces or non-word characters"); 
  }

    //now for the password
    if (!pasw_v.test(pasw)){
    errormsg.push("The Name must not contain spaces or non-word characters"); 
  }

  if (pasw.length < 8) {
      errormsg.push("Password needs to be 8 characters or longer");
  }
  if (pasw = !cpasw) {
      errormsg.push("Passwords must match");
  }

  if (errormsg.length > 0) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
    document.getElementById('errorLog').innerText = errormsg.join('\n'); 
});
```

```html
<div class="formdiv">
    <form id="form" method="post" action="manage.html">
            <h1>Register</h1>

            <label for="email"><b>Email Address</b></label>
      <input id="email" type="email" name="email" required></br>

      <label for="sName"><b>Screen Name</b></label>
      <input id="name" type="text" name="sName" required></br>

      <label for="password"><b>Password</b></label>
      <input id="pasw" type="password" name="password" required></br>

      <label for="cpassword"><b>Confirm Password</b></label>
      <input id="cpasw" type="password" name="cpassword" required></br>

      <label for="file">Select an avatar: </label>
      <input id="avat" type="file" id="file" name="file" required></br>
    
      <button type="submit" id="button2" style="background-color:#4382d4; width: 100%;">Register</button>
    </form>
    <button type="submit" id="button1" style="background-color:#24a149; margin-top:15px;"
</div>
<div id='errorLog'> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should refer the form element in the code rather than the value

```
 var form = document.getElementById("form");
```

Instead you are writing as

```
var form = document.getElementById("form").value; // this is wrong;
```